# Regex to match optional or fixed subdomain, with optional www, fixed domain

Tags: regex

I am trying get a regex to match a url with following rules:

- `https` - mandatory
- `www` - optional
- subdomain, empty or any of `sub1` and `sub2`
- domain - fixed, mandatory. `google.com`

So far I got:
`^https:\/\/(w{0,3})(sub1|sub2)\.google\.com$`

Can't make it work to allow empty subdomain, i tried `(^$|sub1|sub2)` in subdomain capturing group, but doesn't work. Also `.` after `www` or before domain name, it's conditional.

examples:

- `https://google.com` - match
- `https://www.google.com` - match
- `https://sub1.google.com` - match
- `https://www.sub1.google.com` - match
- `https://sub2.google.com` - match
- `https://www.sub2.google.com` - match
- `http:<anything>` - do not match
- `https://sub3.google.com` - do not match

Comment: Share a few example inputs and maybe the desired outputs too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `^https:\/\/(w{0,3}\.)?(sub1\.|sub2\.)?google\.com$`

Test here: https://regex101.com/r/imwunj/1

In your regex dots after www and sub's were not being matched, so once you make them optional, the regex works.

Comment: okayy.. so `?` at the after capturing group, both after www and sub, makes it optional. And adding the . within capturing group makes it part of it.

Comment: this will allow 0 to 3 w, means `https://ww.sub1.google.com` or `https://w.sub1.google.com` will also be valid. So it should be `^https:\/\/(www\.)?(sub1\.|sub2\.)?google\.com$`